# First time customer discount magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to give discount to all new customer to use coupon code or simple discount based on new registered email id. I want to do this from admin panel , I could not find any free module for that, please guide how can I do that

Comment: You may have to write some code yourself. As far as I know, this cannot be done in default Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new customer's group through the `Magento administrative area -> Customers -> Customer Groups -> Add New Customer Group`.

You can set the discount for the newly created group through the `Magento administrative area -> Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules -> Add New Rule`. At the creation page using the Customer Groups fields you can select the customers’ groups for which the promotion will be valid. Enter the other details, set the rule’s actions and conditions. At the end click on the Save Rule button.

Once a customer is registered you can change his/her group through the `Magento administrative area -> Customers -> Manage Customers`. Click on the Edit link besides the customer and change its group through `Account Information -> Customer Group`. When you are ready click on the Save Customer button.

Comment: yeah but how can i create customer group . when i go to customer > customer groups i can not find customer condition to create customer. like customer with sales less that , or order greater that like all. i want to offer discount based on this

Comment: you will see a button Add New Customer Group on right side, go and crated it.

Comment: yeah but i see only:Group Name * and tax class there now way to classify where this customer is new ,or his total order counts to this amount

Comment: yeah i m logged in from main user admin account

Answer (score 8):

You can create Shopping Cart Price Rule that have:

1. Customer Groups without "NOT LOGGED IN".
2. Uses per Customer = 1
3. Coupon = Specific Coupon
4. Coupon Code =  whatever you want.

Then provide it to genneral knowledge.

Comment: But this provide discount for costumers that already made purchases.

Comment: this is not correct as this is all customers who have already some order not First order.